# Vlookup partial values in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to use a vlookup to return values from a range.

The values I have in the range are of the format

```
ABCD1234  
ABCC1233
```

And I want to use just

```
ABCD
```

to return the full `ABCD1234` string.

essentially what I want to do is this:

```
=vlookup("ABCD",LEFT(MYRANGE,4),1,0)
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I believe your formula should work. Just enter your formula as an array formula. In oder to do that just go into the cell where your formula is and instead of pressing Enter to confirm the formula for this cell just press Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead. https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

Comment: If it doesn't work, what kind of error message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a wildcard should achieve what you want:

```
=VLOOKUP("ABCD*", yourRange, 1, 0)
```

Comment: And if i'm using a cell reference instead of "ABCD" then I can use 
=vlookup(A1 & "*", yourRange, 1,0)